# Add new document class

Tags: texlive, visual-studio-code

I am trying to compile my file on VS Code by the Tex-Workshop extension. However when I try to include a new document class

```
\documentclass{amsart}
```

The error message below always comes out

```
There were undefined references. Latex[1,1]
```

which is the line of

```
\documentclass{amsart}
```

So I follow the instructions online, firstly I found the file

```
kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf
```

which is located at the following folder

```
c:/texlive/2020/texmf.cnf
c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

Then I add the following changes

```
TEXMFLOCAL=c:/texlive/myLib
```

into file of

```
c:/texlive/2020/texmf.cnf
```

Then I update with

```
texhash
```

However, in VS Code, it still shows the same error message

Can someone help me on this? By the way, I'm using the Windows.

Comment: If references are undefined, you probably didn't run bibtex? Hard to tell, the info you give is irrelevant.

Comment: @Johannes_B the error happens in the first line of my code which is the \documentclass{amsart}, I re-edit my question now.

Comment: This is no error, but just a warning message that something should be fixed in the best case - it should not be related to a document class change. Please make sure to perform multiple runs of your compiler (PdfLaTeX?), maybe including something like BibTeX in-between. The complete log will usually give you a hint about which references are undefined, so you can attempt to track these down. As already mentioned by Johannes, the information provided in your question are not enough for actual support - please provide a minimal working example (MWE) of your code which reproduces this problem.